# Отображение переменной php

Tags: php

Есть код php:

```
$udlsrokk = " ";
$udlsrok = "0";
if ($udlsrok == "-2") {
    $udlsrokk = "Три;";
} else {
    $udlsrokk = "Два";
} 
echo $udlsrokk;

$perudlsrokk = " ";
if ($udlsrokk = "Три;") {
    $perudlsrokk = -100*2;
}
echo $udlsrokk;
```

Почему `$udlsrokk` в двух случаях разное?

Comment: Потому что не надо присваивать в условии, надо сравнивать!

Comment: А меня одного названия переменных поставили в тупик?)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($udlsrokk = "Три;") {
    $perudlsrokk = -100*2;
}
```

В этом условии всегда будет true т.к. операция присваивания $udlsrokk = "Три;" выполняется в любом случае. Если хотите именно что-то сравнивать, то нужно писать == вместо =

Answer (score 0):

Замените

```
if ($udlsrokk = "Три;")
```

на

```
if ($udlsrokk == "Три;")
```